# how to install bind 9.9.8 or higher on CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, bind, rpm, yum, centos5

I am running a web server based on CentOS 5.8 and I need to upgrade my version of bind to make it PCI compliant. I'm currently running bind 9.3.6 and I need to have bind 9.9.8 or higher. I've tried `yum update bind` but apparently I already have the latest version according to yum. I did some Googling and I found an RPM file `bind-9.10.2-1.el5.i686.rpm` which looks like it would work but i don't know if it should try installing it or not. I think I would need bind-devel and bind-libs which I can get from the same site. Am I better off compiling from source? I know CentOS 5 is old but I'm trying to avoid reinstalling the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

Installing binary rpm's from later versions of CentOS is unlikely to work: there are many changes since CentOS5.

Rebuilding a src.rpm locally is one way to see what issues there are.

Meanwhile, upgrading to CentOS6 (at least: CentOS7 uses systemd which takes some study) is often not a whole lot more effort than retrofitting something like bind, and will have other efficiencies. YMMV, everyone's does.

Comment: Is that RPM from a later version of CentOS? I thought it was for Enterprise Linux 5 because it has 'el5' in the filename. And I thought that CentOS 5 was based on EL5. How do I rebuild a source RPM?

Comment: Yes the .el5 is intended for CentOS5: my comment assumed that you were upgrading from a CentOS6/CentOS7 bind. You will need to upgrade dependencies like bind-devel and bind-libs.